# CSS/JS - Can you treat browser auto line breaks like rows to color them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not quite sure how to put my Question in the right words, but I try to describe what I want to do.

Let's say we have a set of data (eg. numbers) from a database and they need to be output as a list. I put a predefined amount of data-fields in a row (for dekstop systems). Every data is in a SPAN with color/margin/padding styles. (Like table-cells.) After that amount of Spans is reached, a forced line break is given. And with each line break, the background color for all spans in that "row" is altered (odd/even). So far no problem.

However, if now someone checks that page with a Smartphone (or you simple resize your Browser Window), the predefined amount does not fit anmyore. As example, in large resolutions you have 6 Spans side by side, colored odd, than 6 Spans colored even. In a small resolution you maybe only have 3 Spans side by side, however in my design you have still 6 Spans colored odd, so two "rows" with the same background-color before it is altered.

Example HTML Output:

```
<span class="odd">Number 01</span>
<span class="odd">Number 02</span>
<span class="odd">Number 03</span>
<span class="odd">Number 04</span>
<span class="odd">Number 05</span>
<span class="odd">Number 06</span>
<br/>
<span class="even">Number 07</span>
<span class="even">Number 08</span>
<span class="even">Number 09</span>
<span class="even">Number 10</span>
<span class="even">Number 11</span>
<span class="even">Number 12</span>
<br/>
```

I have absolutely no idea if it is possile to get to know - maybe through Javascript or CSS, how many spans are displayed in a "row", to automate the odd-even-coloring, make it in a way responsive.

Check my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9db7p0t/) to maybe show better what I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any way to pull it off with CSS, but here's a javascript solution.  Browser support is a little off.  Didn't realize you tagged jQuery in your post, but it should work on modern browsers at least:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    var cells = document.querySelectorAll('.odd,.even');
    var activeClass='even', activeLine = 0;

    for(var i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; i++) {
        cells[i].classList.remove('odd');
        cells[i].classList.remove('even');
        if(activeLine != cells[i].offsetTop + cells[i].offsetHeight) {
            activeClass = (activeClass === 'even') ? 'odd' : 'even';
            activeLine = cells[i].offsetTop + cells[i].offsetHeight
        }
        cells[i].classList.add(activeClass);
    }
});

/* edit: forgot to dispatch the event.
   jQuery makes this so much easier to write
   than the monstrosity below. */
var event;
event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
event.initEvent("resize", true, true);
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/xh0o6gvy/1

**Edit:**  Here is the jQuery version that Sunny put together found in a fiddle from [the comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33359980#comment54540815_33360308).  It's definitely a better way to go than the above code if compatibility with older browser versions is required.

```
function colorSpans() {
    var containers = $('.span_container');  

    containers.each(function() {
        var activeClass = 'even';        
        var activeLine = 0;
        var cells = $(this).children('.odd, .even');
        cells.each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('odd even');
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var height = $(this).outerHeight();
            if(activeLine != offset.top + height) {
                activeClass = (activeClass === 'even') ? 'odd' : 'even';
                activeLine = offset.top + height;
            }
            $(this).addClass(activeClass);
        });
    });        
}

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    colorSpans();
});

colorSpans();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works like a charm!

I translated this into jQuery and fine-tuned it a bit, so every container starts with an odd row again, your solution altered the color for all "rows" at once. 

Check out my updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/z9db7p0t/1/

Comment: @Sunny Glad to help.  Do you mind if I add the javsascript from your fiddle to my answer for completeness sake?

Comment: Feel free to copy and paste it to your code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Don't you want to use any css framework? Like Bootstrap or Foundation? I hope that will make your work more easier. 
Please go through the link. 
https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

It already has the solution for mobile device and medium screen.

Comment: I know about Bootstrap, thanks, but it's currently no choice because what I have been looking for is just an additon to an existing project that does not use Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody for your help and inspirations!

So just to round it up, here is the final function I am now using that works with fixed and variable container sizes and recolors container by container.

```
function colorSpans() {
    var containers = $('.span_container');  

    containers.each(function() {
        var activeClass = 'even';        
        var activeLine = 0;
        var cells = $(this).children('.odd, .even');
        cells.each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('odd even');
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var height = $(this).outerHeight();
            if(activeLine != offset.top + height) {
                activeClass = (activeClass === 'even') ? 'odd' : 'even';
                activeLine = offset.top + height;
            }
            $(this).addClass(activeClass);
        });
    });        
}
```

An here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z9db7p0t/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this with Javascript or plain CSS depending on the rest of your HTML/CSS.

Are the width of the span elements fixed? What about their parent container? If so, you should know where the breakpoints in your layout exist and easily target the elements via css within the proper media queries.

If the size is dynamic, you could update the classes on the spans by calculating how many spans could fit in a row. This would need to be called each time the page was resized however. Using jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    var container = $('#span-container'),
        spans = container.find('span');

    $(window).on('resize', function(evt) {

        var containerWidth = container.width(),
            spanWidth = spans.width();

        var howManyPerRow = Math.floor(containerWidth / spanWidth);

        //reset rows
        spans.removeClass('odd even');

        var row = 'odd',
            c = 1;

        spans.each(function() {
            $(this).addClass( row );

            if( c % howManyPerRow == 0 ) {
                row = (row == 'odd') ? 'even' : 'odd';
            }

            c++;
        });

    });

});
```

You are going to need to remove the `<br />` tags for this to work correctly. Also, you should set `white-space: nowrap;` on the spans IMO.

Comment: Hey there, nice idea, thanks. I combined your ideas and Josephs setup into the new function that now perfectly fits what I was looking for. My updated fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/z9db7p0t/1/